# PdfReadWarning: impossible to decode XFormObject /SPIPa1 PdfReadWarning,

Tags: python, pypdf

I am using PyPDF2 to read multiple pdf files. My script is as follows:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
flist = os.listdir(pdfFolder)
for f in flist:
    pdfFileObj = open(os.path.join(pdfFolder, f), 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj, strict=False)
    for i in range(0,pdfReader.numPages):
      pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
      text = pageObj.extract_text()
```

I am getting the following warning for some of the pdf files.
"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PyPDF2/_page.py:1240: PdfReadWarning:  impossible to decode XFormObject /SPIPa0
PdfReadWarning,"

I am using PyPDF2 2.1.0. Any leads on the cause of this warning would be helpful.

Comment: Would it be possible to upload the pdf file?

Comment: Please check again with the most recent version. If it still fails, share at least a full traceback

Answer (score 0):

a XFormObject is (Also named as Form XObject) an advanced feature of PDF files. These objects may have their own resources such as images and fonts. Currently, it looks as PdfReader does not have capacity to read such objects. If you are only interested in text in Pdf file, you may ignore this warning and use the output you have gathered. But I would also suggest you to look at Java pdf read methods about this issue.